# How to map existentials with multiple constraints in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I figured out how to process a list of heterogeneous types constrained by a single class:

```
data Ex c = forall a. (c a) => Ex a

forEx :: [Ex c] -> (forall a. c a => a -> b) -> [b] 
forEx [] _ = [] 
forEx (Ex a:r) f = f a : forEx r f

> forEx @Show [Ex 3, Ex (), Ex True] show
["3","()","True"]
```

Looks great, but in real life instead of show function would more complicated one relying on more than 1 constraint.
Going further by analogy doesn't work:

Attempt 1:

```
forEx @(Show, Eq) [Ex 3, Ex (), Ex True] show

<interactive>:85:8: error:
    • Expected kind ‘* -> Constraint’, but ‘(Show, Eq)’ has kind ‘*’
```

Attempt 2:

```
type ShowEq c = (Show c, Eq c)
> forEx @ShowEq [Ex 3, Ex (), Ex True] show

<interactive>:87:1: error:
    • The type synonym ‘ShowEq’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none
```

Attempt 3 works, but defining dummy class and instance for one time use  is to clumsy:

```
class (Show a, Eq a) => ShowEq1 a 
instance (Show a, Eq a) => ShowEq1 a
forEx @ShowEq1 [Ex (3::Int), Ex (), Ex True] show

["3","()","True"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, RankNTypes, StandaloneKindSignatures, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Kind

type All :: [Type -> Constraint] -> Type -> Constraint
type family All cs t
  where All '[] _ = ()
        All (c ': cs) t = (c t, All cs t)

data Ex cs
  where Ex :: All cs t => t -> Ex cs

forEx :: [Ex cs] -> (forall a. All cs a => a -> b) -> [b]
forEx [] _ = []
forEx (Ex x : xs) f = f x : forEx xs f
```

Now `Ex` is parameterised not on a single class but a *list* of classes<sup>1</sup>. And we have the `All` type family for taking a list of classes and applying them all to the same type, combining them into a single `Constraint`.

This means (unlike the class-to-combine-two-other-classes approach) it now supports any number of constraints you need.

You can call it like this<sup>2</sup>:

```
λ forEx @[Show, Eq] [Ex 3, Ex (), Ex True] show
["3","()","True"]
it :: [String]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically not a list of classes, but rather a list of things that need one more type argument to produce a `Constraint`. Single-param classes would be the most common thing you'd use this on, though.

---

<sup>2</sup> Of course `Eq` is not a very useful constraint to have in there, because you can't actually use it without *another* value of the same unknown type, and you've thrown away all the information about whether any given type **is** the same type.

Comment: Is that type family available somewhere as a library?

Comment: @Netsu `All` you mean? Almost certainly it's defined in at least one library. I've needed it a couple of times, but have so far just defined it in the package where I needed it, rather than add a dependency.

Comment: I found only https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.5.1.2/docs/Generics-SOP.html#t:All for list of types, not constraints, unfortunately.

Comment: @Netsu Yeah, it might not be called `All`, which makes it hard to find. There are several variations someone might want when they want something vaguely like this (list of types and single class, list of classes and single type, tuple variations, etc), but it's not common enough a need to have standardised. If you can't find a predefined one after a brief search, just define it in your own project. It's short and very direct, and it's just a type family (so it shouldn't pose compatibility problems if you end up mixing code with someone else's definition of something similar)

Answer (score 3):

With enough language features, it's possible to make a constraint that combines constraints:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ConstraintKinds, GADTs, TypeApplications, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableSuperClasses #-}

data Ex c = forall a. (c a) => Ex a

forEx :: [Ex c] -> (forall a. c a => a -> b) -> [b] 
forEx [] _ = [] 
forEx (Ex a:r) f = f a : forEx r f

class (c a, d a) => (Combined c d) a
instance (c a, d a) => (Combined c d) a

shown :: [String]
shown = forEx @(Combined Show Eq) [Ex 3, Ex (), Ex True] show
```